# Counting Readmissions in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the patient readmissions in my set of data but have to do so using SQL. I am having trouble and hoped someone could point me in the right direction. My data appears like so

> >
>   ID   FirstDateofService  LastDateofService PerformingProvider etc.(more irrelevant rows)
>   2202       2012-09-18       2012-09-21        St. Luke's
>   2202       2012-09-29       2012-10-04        St. Luke's
>   4280       2012-09-19        2012-09-20       Seton
>   4280       2012-09-19       2012-10-18       Seton
>   4280       2012-09-21       2012-10-09       Seton
>   4280       2012-10-10       2012-10-17       Seton
>   8980       2013-06-20       2013-06-24       Denton Regional
>   8980       2013-07-06       2013-07-06       Denton Regional

And the data goes on and on. I am trying to write a query to count the number of re-admissions (would like to do it per ID) where a re-admission is constituted by being admitted after 30 days or less from being released from the same hospital. I have tried many ways but cannot come up with accurate results. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can one patiënt visit multiple providers? For example first Hospital A then Hospital B and then A again. And is the third one considered a readmission from first admission? Or is this considered 2 readmissions?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that people can't get re-admitted on the same day they left. It also assumes that Id is some kind of patient identifier.

```
Select
    Id,
    Count(*) as Readmissions
From
    table a2 -- a2 happens after a1
Where
    Exists (
        Select 'x'
    From
        table a1 
    Where
        a1.Id = a2.Id And
        a1.PerformingProvider = a2.PerformingProvider And
        a1.LastDateOfService < a2.FirstDateOfService And
        dateadd(day, 30, a1.LastDateOfService) >= a2.FirstDateOfService
    )
Group By
    Id
```

Comment: if you replace: a1.LastDateOfService < a2.FirstDateOfService with a1.FirstDateOfService <> a2.FirstDateOfService then you will avoid duplicates and allow people to be readmitted on the same day.  I'm sure it happens :)

Comment: That's better, but would still fail if someone got admitted and released twice on the same day. Really you need a primary key or a db generated rowid

Comment: True.  I was working off the data we were given... and you need a unique key per admission.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*

drop table #t
create table #t (id int, FirstDateOfService datetime, LastDateOfService datetime,         PerformingProvider varchar(30));
go
insert into #t (id, FirstDateOfService, LastDateOfService, PerformingProvider)
values
(2202  , '2012-09-18' , '2012-09-21' ,           'St. Luke''s')
,(2202   , '2012-09-29' , '2012-10-04',            'St. Luke''s')
,(4280   , '2012-09-19' , '2012-09-20',            'Seton')
,(4280   , '2012-09-19' , '2012-10-18',            'Seton')
,(4280   , '2012-09-21' , '2012-10-09',            'Seton')
,(4280   , '2012-10-10' , '2012-10-17',            'Seton')
,(8980   , '2013-06-20' , '2013-06-24',            'Denton Regional')
,(8980   , '2013-07-06' , '2013-07-06' ,           'Denton Regional')
*/
;with cte (rid, id, FirstDateOfService, LastDateOfService, PerformingProvider) 
as (
    select rid=row_number() over (PARTITION BY id order by FirstDateOfService),*
    from #t
)
select t1.id, t1.PerformingProvider, Readmission=count(*)
from cte t1
inner join cte t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.rid = t2.rid-1
and t2.FirstDateOfService < dateadd(day, 30, t1.LastDateOfService)
and t1.PerformingProvider = t2.PerformingProvider
group by t1.id, t1.PerformingProvider
order by t1.id;
```

However I think your data needs to be cleansed. How come id=4280 has two same firstdayofservice (2012-09-19) yet different lastdayofservice?